# c# detectar acceso a servidor desde fuera

Tags: c#, .net

Necesito identificar si el usuario está accediendo desde la empresa o desde fuera y en base a eso usar una ip pública o privada  para redirigir a un sitio.

¿Hay forma de hacerlo? agradezco su ayuda. La aplicación está en c#.

Comment: Deberías manejar un grupo de red para identificar si la aplicación es accedida desde intranet y puedas usar el link interno, en caso contrario la externa. Puedes revisar [How to check a input IP fall in a specific IP range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138706/how-to-check-a-input-ip-fall-in-a-specific-ip-range) y , lamento que esté en inglés. Recuerda que una PC pueda tener varias IPs, se basa en la cantidad de interfaces que tenga instalada.

Comment: Si tu red interna es estándar, su IP puede empezar con `10` para clase A, `172.16` para clase B y `192.168` para clases C... solo tienes que identificar que IP usa tu intranet y a partir de ahí decidir que visor enviar.